# Why is this question about Google Docs closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question was closed: [Google Docs shared link requires login to edit document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100676/16011)

The closure text says:

> This question does not appear to be about web applications within the scope defined in the help center.

But the help center says:

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The question is about Google Docs, which even has its own tag : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs

Why does the question not meet the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100676/google-docs-shared-link-requires-login-to-edit-document#comment96952_100676)

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could not be reproduced as of 9/8/2017. – jonsca♦ Sep 21 '17 at 0:50

Comment: You are right. I jumped the gun because of [this recent comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100676/google-docs-shared-link-requires-login-to-edit-document#comment134264_100676) saying it does not work again.